# REACT + PHP - blocked my CORS policy only in POST request

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, fetch-api

**Overview** 
My **react app** is hosted on **githup-pages** and a **PHP API** is hosted on a standard, paid hosting.

**This works (GET)** 
When I started developing my app, I encountered a pretty popular error, which is `Access to fetch at ... has been blocked by CORS policy`. I have found a quick-fix which was to write this `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")` in the PHP's first lines and it **worked**. However those were the **GET requests**.

**This doesn't work (POST)** 
This time I have a piece of code in which I have to use a **POST** request and need to access it's response. This is the piece of code responsible for sending the post request:

```
const editEvent = async () => {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', },
        body: JSON.stringify({ eventID: chosenEvent, courseID: courseID, groupID: groupID, time:time, date: date, description: description, typeID: typeID, password: password}),
        mode: 'cors',
    };
    const response = await fetch(`https://aleksanderblaszkiewicz.pl/kiedykolos/edit_event.php`, requestOptions);
}
```

It happened again - I am getting same error `Access to fetch at ... has been blocked by CORS policy`. Solution which I am using now is to use `mode: 'no cors'` but it doesn't let me to get the response as it is opaque. Another solution I have found is to add more headers:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Application");
```

But it doesn't work as well. Any suggestions? Full error code:

> Access to fetch at 'https://aleksanderblaszkiewicz.pl/kiedykolos/add_event.php' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Full PHP code:

```php
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Application");
$servername = "...";
$username = "...";
$password = "...";
$dbname = "...";

$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8'); 

if ($connection -> connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $connection -> connect_error;
  exit();
}

$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);

$courseID = $input["courseID"];
$groupID = $input["groupID"];
$date = $input["date"];
$time = $input["time"];
$description = $input["description"];
$typeID = $input["typeID"];
$password = $input["password"];

$sql = "INSERT 
        INTO `events` (`id`, `date`, `time`, `description`, `course_fk`, `year_group_fk`, `type_fk`)
        VALUES (NULL, '$date', '$time', '$description', '$courseID', '$groupID', '$typeID')";

if($password == "Ujebale321!") {
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
  echo "Success";
}
else {
  echo "Wrong password";
}


mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225763/discussion-on-question-by-ablaszkiewicz1-react-php-blocked-my-cors-policy-on).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that your server set a number of allowed headers that are not part of the **origin request**. The only request header in your Fetch object is `content-type: application/json`, so must match the Access-Control-Allow-Headers in you server.

> The Access-Control-Request-Headers header is used when issuing a preflight request to let the server know what HTTP headers will be used when the actual request is made (such as with setRequestHeader()). This browser side header will be answered by the complementary server side header of Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

[Source Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

This is a potential solution that will make your CORS request work:

```
  // In your code, this function is never called...
  const editEvent = async () => {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', },
            body: JSON.stringify({ eventID: chosenEvent, courseID: courseID, groupID: groupID, time:time, date: date, description: description, typeID: typeID, password: password}),
        };
        await fetch(`https://aleksanderblaszkiewicz.pl/kiedykolos/edit_event.php`, requestOptions)
          .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))
          .catch(error => console.log(error))


    }
```

This is a pre-flight request because the content-type is application/json.
This means the browser make a "pre-request" to the server to see if the request can be executed (and the response be sent).

Thus, in your server-side code, you can only use:

```
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000");
```

Or:

```
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

If you want to include another response header beside the Access-Control-Allow-Origin, allow just the `content-type` header, which is the one you set in your origin Fetch request:

```
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
```

Comment: Previously I have been trying ```response.json()``` but I have been told by the console that it is not possible as response is empty. I have changed the ```Access-Control-Allow-Origin``` to a ```*``` and it gives no results (I had this set-up this way previously and changed to localhost for testing purposes)

Comment: Also - removed ```mode: cors``` as you said and it gives no positive result. What is interesting is that at the very beggining I've been getting those CORS errors also in GET requests but putting ```Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *``` in a PHP file solved the issue. It didn't solve the POST issues however.

Comment: I am out of my mind. I'll try to contact my hosting tomorrow. Maybe there is something wrong with it?

Comment: do you still get the error or the issue is now the response is empty? can you implement my suggestions as above and let me know if you still have the error, the type of error, or if now the issue is different

Comment: I am still getting the same error. CORS error

Comment: let s move this to private chat and get it sorted !

Comment: How do I do this? Have never done that before

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225739/help-for-user-ablaszkiewicz1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225740/discussion-between-rags2riches-and-ablaszkiewicz1).

Comment: Did you receive the notification?

Comment: sorry I thought you were away and I've been afk. I am there now though

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in your **php** file and while calling the api in React JS use **Axios** instead of Fetch

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
die();
}
```